# Placing characters of a text exactly in grid boxes (w/ TikZ grid)

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, exercises, xlop

For generating a large number of Exercise-sheets for my math class I'd like to set the problem in a grid so the kids have a given structure to add their calculation.

Example with quite a large code chunk from Gonzalo Medina's answer to [Change display style in xlop package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110050/change-display-style-in-xlop-package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[]{xlop}


%% this part is from 
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110050/change-display-style-in-xlop-package
%% Answer by Gonzalo Medina

\makeatletter
\def\op@divdisplayone{%
  \begingroup
    \op@count@z=\z@\relax
    \op@count@i=\OP@a@w
    \loop
    \ifnum\@nameuse{OP@a@\the\op@count@i}=0
      \advance\op@count@i by-1
      \advance\op@count@z by1
    \repeat
    \op@count@i=\op@firstlength
    \advance\op@count@i by\op@count@z
    \xdef\op@firstlength{\the\op@count@i}%
    \setbox2=\vbox{%
      \op@count@i=\op@firstlength
      \advance\op@count@i by1
      \hbox{%
        \ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@none\else
% add 0.25
          \ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@None\else
% end add 0.25
            \kern\opcolumnwidth
            \advance\op@count@i by1
% add 0.25
          \fi
% end add 0.25
        \fi
        \ifop@dividendbridge
          \vrule width0pt depth0pt height\oplineheight 
          \opvline(0,1){0.4}%
          \ophline(0,1){\op@firstlength}%
          \opvline(\op@firstlength,1){0.4}%
        \fi
        \op@display{operandstyle.1}{a}%
        \ifnum\op@shift=0\relax\else
          \op@count@v=\op@shift
          \advance\op@count@v by\OP@a@d
          \oplput(-\the\op@count@v,0){\op@strikedecimalsepsymbol}%
        \fi
      }%
      \op@count@z=\OP@q@w
      \op@count@ii=1\relax
      \ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@none
        \advance\op@count@i by-1\relax
% add 0.25
      \else\ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@None
        \advance\op@count@i by-1\relax
% end add 0.25
      \else
        \op@count@iv=\@nameuse{OP@q@\the\op@count@z}\relax
        \op@count@iii=\op@count@i
        \advance\op@count@iii by-\@nameuse{OP@T\the\op@count@iv @w}%
        \hbox{%
          % \ifx\op@voperator\op@string@center
          %   \oplput(0,0.5){\op@subsymbol}%
          % \else\ifx\op@voperator\op@string@top
          %   \oplput(0,1){\op@subsymbol}%
          % \else
            \oplput(0,0){\op@subsymbol}%
          % \fi\fi
          \ophline(1,-0.25){\op@firstlength}%
          \advance\op@count@ii by1
          \kern\op@count@iii\opcolumnwidth
          \op@display{intermediarystyle.1}%
                     {T\the\op@count@iv}%
        }%
% modif 0.25
      \fi\fi
% end modif 0.25
      {\global\setbox4=\hbox{}\setbox4=\box4}%
      \loop
        \advance\op@count@z by-1
        \advance\op@count@i by1\relax
      \ifnum\op@count@z>0\relax
        \op@count@iv=\@nameuse{OP@q@\the\op@count@z}\relax
        \ifnum\op@count@iv=0
          \ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@all
            \op@count@v=\op@count@i
            \advance\op@count@v by-\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @w}%
            \hbox{%
              \kern\op@count@v\opcolumnwidth
              \op@display{remainderstyle.\the\op@count@ii}%
                         {R\the\op@count@ii}%
            }%
            \op@count@iii=\op@count@i
            \advance\op@count@iii by-\@nameuse{OP@T\the\op@count@iv @w}%
            \hbox{%
              \kern\op@count@v\opcolumnwidth
              % \ifx\op@voperator\op@string@center
              %   \oplput(-1,0.5){\op@subsymbol}%
              % \else\ifx\op@voperator\op@string@top
              %   \oplput(-1,1){\op@subsymbol}%
              % \else
                \oplput(-1,0){\op@subsymbol}%
              % \fi\fi
              \ophline(0,-0.25){\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @w}}%
              \kern-\op@count@v\opcolumnwidth
              \kern\op@count@iii\opcolumnwidth
              \op@display{intermediarystyle.\the\op@count@ii}%
                         {T\the\op@count@iv}%
            }%
          \else
            \ifnum\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @w}=2
              \ifnum\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @2}=0
                \op@makebox{1}{0}{remainderstyle.\the\op@count@ii.1}{zero}%
                \setbox4=\hbox to\opcolumnwidth{\hss\box0\hss}%
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
          \advance\op@count@ii by1\relax
        \else
          \op@count@v=\op@count@i
          \advance\op@count@v by-\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @w}%
          \ifvoid4\relax\else
            \advance\op@count@v by-1
          \fi
          \hbox{%
            \kern\op@count@v\opcolumnwidth\copy4
            \op@display{remainderstyle.\the\op@count@ii}%
                       {R\the\op@count@ii}%
          }%
          \advance\op@count@ii by1\relax
          \ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@none
% add 0.25
          \else\ifx\op@displayintermediary\op@string@None
% end add 0.25
          \else
            \op@count@iii=\op@count@i
            \advance\op@count@iii by-\@nameuse{OP@T\the\op@count@iv @w}%
            \hbox{%
              \kern\op@count@v\opcolumnwidth
              % \ifx\op@voperator\op@string@center
              %   \oplput(-1,0.5){\op@subsymbol}%
              % \else\ifx\op@voperator\op@string@top
              %   \oplput(-1,1){\op@subsymbol}%
              % \else
                \oplput(-1,0){\op@subsymbol}%
              % \fi\fi
              \advance\op@count@ii by-1
              \ifvoid4\relax
                \ophline(0,-0.25){\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @w}}%
              \else
                \ophline(0,-0.25){\@nameuse{OP@T\the\op@count@iv @w}}%
                \ophline(\@nameuse{OP@T\the\op@count@iv @w},-0.25){1}%
                {\setbox4=\box4}%
              \fi
              \advance\op@count@ii by1
              \kern-\op@count@v\opcolumnwidth
              \kern\op@count@iii\opcolumnwidth
              \op@display{intermediarystyle.\the\op@count@ii}%
                         {T\the\op@count@iv}%
            }%
% modif 0.25
          \fi\fi
% end modif 0.25
        \fi
      \repeat
      \advance\op@count@i by-1
      \op@count@iii=\op@count@i
      \advance\op@count@iii by-\@nameuse{OP@R\the\op@count@ii @w}%
      \hbox{%
        \kern\op@count@iii\opcolumnwidth
        \op@display{remainderstyle.\the\op@count@ii}%
                   {R\the\op@count@ii}%
      }%
    }%
    \setbox3=\vbox{%
      \op@count@v=\op@max{\OP@qq@w}{\OP@b@w}
      \hbox{%\ophline(-0.5,-0.25){\the\op@count@v.5}%
            \op@display{operandstyle.2}{b}%
        \ifnum\op@shift=0\relax\else
          \op@count@v=\op@shift
          \advance\op@count@v by\OP@b@d
          \oplput(-\the\op@count@v,0){\op@strikedecimalsepsymbol}%
        \fi}
      %\hbox{XXX\op@display{resultstyle}{qq}}
    }%
    \dimen0=\ht2
    \ifdim\dimen0>\ht3
      \ht3=\ht2
    \else
      \ht2=\ht3
    \fi
    \ifx\op@voperation\op@string@top
      \dimen0=\ht2
      \advance\dimen0 by-0.5\oplineheight
      \ht2=0.75\oplineheight
      \ht3=0.75\oplineheight
      \dp2=\dimen0
      \dp2=\dimen0
    \fi
    \setbox1=\hbox{%
      \box2
      \kern0.5\opcolumnwidth
      \kern-0.5\op@hrulewidth
      \ifx\voperation\op@string@top
        KKK\vrule width\op@hrulewidth
      \else
        : %\vrule width\op@hrulewidth :@:
      \fi
      \kern0.5\opcolumnwidth
      \kern-0.5\op@hrulewidth
      \box3
      = \hbox{\op@display{resultstyle}{qq}}
    }%
    \ifx\op@voperation\op@string@center
      \setbox1=\hbox{$\vcenter{\box1}$}%
    \fi
    \leavevmode\box1
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\opset{divsymbol={$\colon$}}

\newcommand\hole[1]{\texttt{\_}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\karos}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (#1 cm ,#2 cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


%% here is my sample

\begin{document}   

I'd like to set this

$$154548 \colon 86 =$$

so that each numeral uses one cell of the grid starting top--left

\karos{9}{5} % Karos der Breite 8cm und Höhe 3cm

so the kids can fill out the whole calculation:

\opidiv[voperation=top,displayintermediary=all,maxdivstep=30]{154548}{86}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to set this like

```
\karos{8}{5}{154548 \colon 86 =}
```

so I can generate a large number of execise sheets with a series of identical commands (I intend to write a shell or perl script using random number generator for this task).

Comment: How about this question??  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228846/how-to-fit-characters-numbers-into-a-graph-paper

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not really clear what the output is supposed to be.

Comment: Here are some of my answers related to arithmetic practice: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213357/addition-with-3-elements-using-xlop/219509#219509, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219090/writing-manual-summation-of-two-numbers/219113#219113

Comment: Thank you @StevenB.Segletes for this link.
This is almost exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Steven I found quite a nice solution.

I reduced the Solution found in [How to fit characters (numbers) into a graph paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228846/how-to-fit-characters-numbers-into-a-graph-paper) to my needs:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{gridypos}
\newenvironment{squaredpaper}[3][.5cm]{\obeyspaces% 
  \setcounter{gridypos}{#3}
  \newcommand\gridtext[1]{
    \node[anchor=west,black] at (0,0) [yshift=\value{gridypos}*#1-.5*#1]%
    {%
      \hspace{-.25\dimexpr#1\relax}%
      \spaceout{#1}{##1}%
    };
    \addtocounter{gridypos}{-1}%Next \gridtext one line lower
  }
  % Make the grid
  % Source: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2639/wie-kann-ich-kastchenpapier-zeichnen
  \begin{tikzpicture}[gray,step=#1]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (#2*#1,#3*#1) (0,0) grid (#2*#1,#3*#1);
  }{
  \end{tikzpicture} 
}

\newcommand\spaceout[2]{\def\charwd{#1}\spaceouthelp#2\relax\relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx#1\relax\else%
    \makebox[\charwd]{#1}%
    \spaceouthelp#2\relax%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand{\Aufgabe}[3]{
  \begin{squaredpaper}{#1}{#2}
    \gridtext{#3}    
  \end{squaredpaper}
}

\begin{document} 

\ttfamily%\scriptsize% WILL WORK IF UNCOMMENTED
\Aufgabe{16}{10}{154548{$\colon$}86=}

\end{document}
```

Once I figured out, that Math-Mode will only work when embraced and must fit in one cell, it was quite easy.

Thank you for this quick solution.

This is how it looks like:

```
\Aufgabe{16}{10}{154548{$\colon$}86=}
```

[image]

Comment: This is how I use it together with luacode:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oup3atab9694and/AADIBN5cCJMkTHg-qsjr1fUea?dl=0

Comment: Cool!... but what if you want to write text? for example for explaining the resolution of the division?